# Besides salmon, what other meats can be grilled on a cedar plank?

Tags: grilling, salmon, cedar-plank

I've fallen in love with this wonderful [Cedar Planked Salmon recipe](http://allrecipes.com//Recipe/cedar-planked-salmon-2/Detail.aspx) - the two times I've made it have turned out excellently!

What other meats (or meat substitutes) can be grilled on cedar and not take on too much of the distinctive wood flavor?

Answer (score 10):

Everything. Chicken works well. Pork and brisket taste great after taking on the smokey flavor. A ham steak would be good too.

Answer (score 6):

Try bacon! It smells wonderful cooked on a plank.

Answer (score 5):

Wow, if you haven't tried pork chops on a plank you are missing out. I've tried all types of fish. I read a blog about cooking turkey. http://www.outdoorgourmet.com has a pretty wide variety of recipes for all kinds of things. I think I even saw one for filet mignon.

Answer (score 1):

Fish, of all varieties. For a quick sandwich, try throwing on some sliced ham or turkey, that should be a winner.